# How do we get the readable string from big endian hex string

Tags: string, character-encoding, ascii, hex

How do we get the readable string from hex string

0049006e00740072006f
of BE which means as normal word, ie. we dont have to swap the byte pair per word

tried with xxd in vain, cause I dont know anything of it:

```
$ xxd <<<0049006e00740072006f
00000000: 3030 3439 3030 3665 3030 3734 3030 3732  0049006e00740072
00000010: 3030 3666 3030 3634 3030 3735 3030 3633  006f006400750063
```

Answer (score 2):

You are supplying your value as a string, not as hex!

If you want `xxd` to interpret it as raw hex, you need to use `-` to read from stdin.

Use the `-r` flag for reverse operation, and `-p` to output in postscript style.

```
xxd -r -p - <<< 0049006e00740072006f
```

returns

```
Intro
```

Comment: @PhilipCouling Thank you for the suggestion, I have edited the answer.